# Am I sinning if I refuse to help a stranger who asked me for help?

Tags: practical-islam, helping

Salam Alaikoum,

How to explain to a stranger man (that I never seen in my life), and who asked me to stay few nights in my room (I live in one room of 12 square meters) and to whom I proposed to pay to him some nights in Hotel (he refused money and hotel), and who said that he really got some big troubles with local administration (Really big troubles) That I am sorry and except giving financials helps, I can not propose to him to share my room.

Am I wrong and a bad person if to say that ?

Comment: Wa alaikum salaam, from your description it is clear that you are a very good person because you did not refuse to help  and you offered him financial help. You did what was in your capacity, if he refuses to take the money it's his decision. You definitely did not commit a sin by not accommodating him in your home. Please be cautious, as the man is a stranger to you and you do not know his intentions.

Comment: Thank you @Noor , just to explain why I decided to ask and look for help (and more points of view from other brothers and sisters), It is because when I told my friends about this story, some of them were saying that I was rude and maybe not enough helpfull.